# Pairing a new Logitech mouse with non-unifying receiver

Tags: keyboard, mouse, logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard

I have a Logitech keyboard and a mouse pair (keyboard K270 and mouse M185) that are paired to a single **non-unifying** receiver, and they work (I bought them together as a pair). Now one button in the mouse stopped working so I bought a new M185 mouse, but I can't pair it with the older receiver using Logitech's Connect Utility (version 2.30.90). I do as the instructions say (turn it off then on again) but the utility doesn't recognize it (I tried this strategy to re-pair the older keyboard and it worked). The new mouse works with its dedicated receiver that came with it, so I know that the mouse is OK. But why can't I pair it with the older receiver (with or without the keyboard)? I also tried pairing the keyboard with the new mouse's receiver, but failed (the Connect Utility doesn't recognize that receiver at all - it says no receiver is connected - although the mouse is working just fine with it).

Is there any way to pair the old keyboard and the new mouse with the same non-unifying receiver? What other alternatives do I have besides plugging to receivers simultaneously?

Comment: Try different peering software - https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024840533--Downloads-Wireless-Mouse-M185 is, I believe recommended.

Comment: @davidgo - Same problem. With the keyboard's receiver, it won't pair the mouse, and with the mouse's receiver it won't even recognize the receiver (again, although mouse is functioning)

Answer (score 4):

Logitech's receivers are not interchangeable.
They're either not-really-wifi or not-really-bluetooth, they won't link to anything except the 'family' they're designed for.

Logi change the dongle requirements over time. If you have an older keyboard & a newer mouse, even though they are supposedly "the same thing" they may be using different versions of the dongle technology. As far as I'm aware, nothing still uses the old Connect* software, which I think was for the receivers with a physical button. Later dongles were paired for life with the device they came in the box with, no mix & match at all. At least with the new Unifying dongles, you can manually pair several devices.

Thanks to [roaima](https://superuser.com/users/332907/roaima) for the comment - there's a re-pairing utility [Logitech Connection Utility](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-my/articles/360025141574) available [for Windows only] which may help.

See [How do Logitech keyboards coexist? What if I mix up the USB dongles?](https://superuser.com/questions/1185591/how-do-logitech-keyboards-coexist-what-if-i-mix-up-the-usb-dongles) for how these 'mid-period' dongles worked.

*These days, there's 'Logitech Options', 'Set Point' and the newest 'Logi Options+', depending on hardware/OS.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not interchangeable", because I was able to pair my keyboard with a different receiver. Also can you explain what you mean by "family"? Because the new mouse is literally the exact model of the old one.

Comment: Logi change the dongle requirements over time. If you have an older keyboard & a newer mouse, even though they are supposedly "the same thing" they may be using different versions of the dongle technology. As far as I'm aware, nothing still uses the old 'Connect' software, which I think was for the receivers with a physical button. Later dongles were paired for life with the device they came in the box with, no mix & match at all. At least with the new Unifying dongles, you can manually pair several devices. Added to answer.

Comment: "_Later dongles were paired for life with the device they came in the box with, no mix & match at all_" - I've got a collection of keyboard/mouse/dongle units which use non-unifying dongles. The [re-pairing program](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-my/articles/360025141574) works well for these.

Comment: @roaima - ah, cool, but Windows only, so I can't test. I used to have a lot of Wintel machines but nothing except VMs these days. I'll add it to the answer, thanks.